# Out of index when traversing multiple lists of different length

Tags: python, list

I'm doing a python challenge where i'm required to traverse multiple lists, one element by time, and return some calculations based on it. I have lists like:

```
a = [2,3,4,5]
b = [7,8,9,0,7]
c = [a, b]
```

and i need to traverse them in a column fashion, like this:

```
2 3 4
7 8 9...
```

I've seen that many of you are able to do this thanks to the itertools, but i'm unable to import any library. My problem is, with my current solution, that my second index goes out of range for values that are greater than the current lists element, and I'm unable to find a condition to not make that happen.
I already tried slicing the list but i think i will be much faster if i do not do it. Here is my code for reference, where players[i][rounds] returns in column style like i described earlier.

```
while not(0 in dim_hands):
        for i in range(0, 4):
            if rounds > len(players[i]):
                #do something
        
            word = (players[i][rounds])
            num_letters = num_letters - word
        
            if num_letters < 0:
                dim_hands[i] -= abs(num_letters)
                num_letters = 0

        rounds += 1
```

Is there any other way to do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'd be much quicker with `itertools` as you've mentioned, or with `numpy` but since you can't use any imports let's solve it the old fashioned way:

We will start by preparing the length of the data that we're gonna iterate on, we will make it the minimum length between the two lists so we wouldn't get an exception:

```
min_length = min(len(a), len(b))
```

Then we will iterate the length and print the two arrays at a time:

```
for i in range(min_length):
    print(f'{a[i]}, {b[i]}')
```

That way we guarantee we will only print elements at positions that are in both arrays.

I hope this is what you were aiming for, if not please elaborate and I will fix :)